# Regular expression for duplicate words

Tags: regex, duplicates, backreference, capture-group

I'm a regular expression newbie and I can't quite figure out how to write a single regular expression that would "match" any duplicate consecutive words such as:

> Paris in **the the** spring.
>
> Not **that that** is related.
>
> Why are you laughing?  Are **my my** regular expressions THAT bad??

Is there a single regular expression that will match ALL of the bold strings above?

Comment: @poly: That was no "accusation", but a calm, normal question that perfectly can take a "no" as an answer. @Joshua: Yes, some people (not too few) let this site do their homework for them. But asking homework questions is not a bad thing to do on SO, when they are tagged as such. Usually the style of the answers changes from "here is the solution" to "here are some things you have not thought about", and that is a good thing. Somebody has to try and keep up the distinction, in his case it was me, and elsewhere "other people" do the same thing. That's all.

Comment: Hope to never see a question like "This sounds a bit like a workplace question. Is it?" and then people will argue if stack overflow is doing someone's job.

Comment: @Joshua +1 with respect to the regex solution you accepted, could you please tell me how could I replace the matches (duplicates) by one element of the pair (e.g., `not that that is related` -> `not that is related`)? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Joshua I think I found the solution: I should replace by `\1`!

Comment: This solution handle consecutive duplicate words, what about the more generic situation: when the number of duplicated words is greater than 2?, for example: "Not that **that that** is related".

Comment: @DavidLeal How about `\b(\w+)\s+(\1\s*)+\b`?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51190570/3832970) deals with both consecutive and non-consecutive duplicate words.

Comment: careful though: "not that that's related. But..." could be proper grammar. Or at least usage. But that that in other contexts is perfectly correct (...so that that nation can exist...)

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
\b(\w+)\s+\1\b
```

Here `\b` is a word boundary and `\1` references the captured match of the first group.

Regex101 example [here](https://regex101.com/r/DlNrO4/1)

Comment: Makes me wonder; is it possible to do `\0` too? (Where `\0` is the whole regex, up to the current point OR where `\0` refers to the whole regex)

Comment: @Pindatjuh: No, I don’t think so because that sub-match would also be part of the whole match.

Comment: At least works on the regex engine used in the Eclipse search/replace dialog.

Comment: This would treat hyphens etc. as marking a word boundary, e.g. `the the-foo bar`. @Daniel's answer is slightly more correct.

Comment: Just a warning, this does not handle words with apostrophes or (as Noel mentions) hypens. Mike's solution works better in these cases

Comment: Moreover, it won't catch triplicates (or more), not when one of the dup/triplicate is at the end of the string

Comment: +1 nice solution. Could you tell me how to replace the matches (duplicates) with the first element of the pair (e.g., `and and` should become `and`)?

Comment: Don't know it does not work in Python, the regex looks good to me. When I try to call match function, it always returns `None`

Comment: @LucasHuang Try `re.search`. See [search() vs. match()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Comment: and If I want to find all consecutive words from a particular tag, such as `<p class="bebe">bla bla</p>` how can I integrate this regex formula?

Comment: Doesn't work when the 2nd word is the last word on the line. The regex `\b(\w+)\s+\1$` works in those cases but that doesn't work when the 2nd word is *not* at the end of a line. Any ideas? \[edit\] Found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9005999/1052284): `\b(\w+)\s+\1(?:\s|$)`

Comment: What If I want to capture any number of repetations of a word?

Answer (score 32):

I believe this regex handles more situations:

```
/(\b\S+\b)\s+\b\1\b/
```

A good selection of test strings can be found here:  http://callumacrae.github.com/regex-tuesday/challenge1.html

Comment: Great, works with apostrophes/hyphens/etc. too - thanks!

Comment: for the challenge1 link, what do you place in the replace area to use the grouped word? Tried `<strong>\0</strong>` but not working.

Comment: It won't catch triplicates (or more), not when one of the dup/triplicate is at the end of the string

Comment: @uptownhr You want to use `$1 <strong>$2</strong>`. But also use different regex `/\b(\S+) (\1)\b/gi`. Here is a link: https://callumacrae.github.io/regex-tuesday/challenge1.html?find=%2F%5Cb(%5CS%2B)%20(%5C1)%5Cb%2Fgi&replace=%241%20%3Cstrong%3E%242%3C%2Fstrong%3E

Comment: and If I want to find all consecutive words from a particular tag, such as `<p class="bebe">bla bla</p>` how can I integrate this regex formula?

Comment: The `\b` (word boundary metacharacter ) followed by `\s` (a non-word metacharacter)  will demand that the last character matched by `\S` MUST be a "word character" (`\w`) -- so this will technically cover more scenarios, but is a little misleading to those who don't know how `\b` behaves.

Answer (score 25):

The below expression should work correctly to find any number of duplicated words. The matching can be case insensitive.

```
String regex = "\\b(\\w+)(\\s+\\1\\b)+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

// Check for subsequences of input that match the compiled pattern
while (m.find()) {
     input = input.replaceAll(m.group(0), m.group(1));
}
```

Sample Input : Goodbye goodbye GooDbYe

Sample Output : Goodbye

Explanation:

The regex expression:

\b : Start of a word boundary

\w+ : Any number of word characters

(\s+\1\b)* : Any number of space followed by word which matches the previous word and ends the word boundary. Whole thing wrapped in * helps to find more than one repetitions.

Grouping :

m.group(0) : Shall contain the matched group in above case Goodbye goodbye GooDbYe

m.group(1) : Shall contain the first word of the matched pattern in above case Goodbye

Replace method shall replace all consecutive matched words with the first instance of the word.

Answer (score 13):

Try this with below RE

- \b     start of word word boundary
- \W+    any word character
- \1     same word matched already
- \b     end of word
- ()*     Repeating again

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      String regex = "\\b(\\w+)(\\b\\W+\\b\\1\\b)*";//  "/* Write a RegEx matching repeated words here. */";
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE/* Insert the correct Pattern flag here.*/);

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      int numSentences = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

      while (numSentences-- > 0) {
          String input = in.nextLine();

          Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

          // Check for subsequences of input that match the compiled pattern
          while (m.find()) {
              input = input.replaceAll(m.group(0),m.group(1));
          }

          // Prints the modified sentence.
          System.out.println(input);
      }

      in.close();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 12):

#### Regex to Strip 2+ duplicate words (consecutive/non-consecutive words)

Try this regex that can catch 2 or more duplicate words and only leave behind one single word. And the duplicate words **need not even be consecutive**.

```
/\b(\w+)\b(?=.*?\b\1\b)/ig
```

Here, `\b` is used for Word Boundary, `?=` is used for positive lookahead, and `\1` is used for back-referencing.

**[Example](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=104060)
[Source](https://digitalfortress.tech/tips/top-15-commonly-used-regex/)**

Comment: Non-consecutive is a bad idea: `"the cat sat on the mat"` -> `" cat sat on the mat"`

Comment: @Walf True. Nevertheless, there are scenarios where this is intended. (for example: whilst scraping data)

Comment: Why'd you [break your regex again](https://regex101.com/r/XuTNPS/1) after [I corrected it](https://regex101.com/r/Cw8SmI/2)? Did you think I had changed its intent? Even the example you linked doesn't have the mistake.

Comment: Yep, it was a mistake, copy pasted the wrong stuff. Intended to copy the one from my example actually. anyway, it now works! so all good! Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar use case to remove duplicate characters from a string in java and your solution helped me. Thanks. If anyone else is looking for the code to remove duplicate chars from String in java - s1.replaceAll("(.)(?=.*?\\1)", "")

Answer (score 8):

The widely-used PCRE library can handle such situations (you won't achieve **the the** same with POSIX-compliant regex engines, though):

```
(\b\w+\b)\W+\1
```

Comment: You need something to match the characters *between* the two words, like `\W+`.  `\b` won't do it, because it doesn't consume any characters.

Comment: This will potentially result in false-positive matching in cases like `... the these problems...`.  This solution is not as reliable as the general structure of Gumbo's pattern which sufficiently implements word boundaries.

Comment: and If I want to find all consecutive words from a particular tag, such as `<p class="bebe">bla bla</p>` how can I integrate this regex formula?

Answer (score 5):

Here is one that catches multiple words multiple times:

```
(\b\w+\b)(\s+\1)+
```

Comment: and If I want to find all consecutive words from a particular tag, such as `<p class="bebe">bla bla</p>` how can I integrate this regex formula?

Comment: I believe that will require HTML parsing. For any given tag that you wish to search, find all tag occurrences inside the HTML, and run this regex one by one on each one. Or if you dont care about where in the HTML does the repetition occur, concatenate all the tag text attributes and run the regex on the concatenated string

Comment: I find myself the answer `<p class="bebe">.*?\b\s+(\w+)\b\K\s+\1\s+\b(?=.*?<\/p>)`

Answer (score 4):

No. That is an irregular grammar. There may be engine-/language-specific regular expressions that you can use, but there is no universal regular expression that can do that.

Comment: Though being correct in a strict sense, I believe there is no regex engine in serious use anymore that does not support grouping and back-references.

Answer (score 4):

This is the regex I use to remove duplicate phrases in my twitch bot:

```
(\S+\s*)\1{2,}
```

`(\S+\s*)` looks for any string of characters that isn't whitespace, followed whitespace.

`\1{2,}` then looks for more than 2 instances of that phrase in the string to match. If there are 3 phrases that are identical, it matches.

Comment: This answer is misleading.  It does not hunt duplicates, it hunts substrings with 3 or more occurrences.  It is also not very robust because of the `\s*` in the capture group.  See this demonstration: https://regex101.com/r/JtCdd6/1

Comment: Furthermore extreme cases (low-frequency text) would produce false positive matches.  E.g. `I said "oioioi" that's some wicked mistressship!` on `oioioi` and `sss`

Answer (score 3):

Since some developers are coming to this page in search of a solution which not only eliminates duplicate consecutive non-whitespace substrings, but triplicates and beyond, I'll show the adapted pattern.

Pattern: `/(\b\S+)(?:\s+\1\b)+/` ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dI9Jbh/1))
Replace: `$1` (replaces the fullstring match with capture group #1)

This pattern greedily matches a "whole" non-whitespace substring, then requires one or more copies of the matched substring which may be delimited by one or more whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, etc).

Specifically:

- `\b` (word boundary) characters are vital to ensure partial words are not matched.
- The second parenthetical is a non-capturing group, because this variable width substring does not need to be captured -- only matched/absorbed.
- the `+` (one or more quantifier) on the non-capturing group is more appropriate than `*` because `*` will "bother" the regex engine to capture and replace singleton occurrences -- this is wasteful pattern design.

*note if you are dealing with sentences or input strings with punctuation, then the pattern will need to be further refined.

Answer (score 2):

The example in Javascript: The Good Parts can be adapted to do this:

```
var doubled_words = /([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2800-\uFFFD]+)\s+\1(?:\s|$)/gi;
```

\b uses \w for word boundaries, where \w is equivalent to [0-9A-Z_a-z]. If you don't mind that limitation, the accepted answer is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This expression (inspired from Mike, above) seems to catch all duplicates, triplicates, etc, including the ones at the end of the string, which most of the others don't:

```
/(^|\s+)(\S+)(($|\s+)\2)+/g, "$1$2")
```

I know the question asked to match *duplicates* only, but a triplicate is just 2 duplicates next to each other :)

First, I put `(^|\s+)` to make sure it starts with a full word, otherwise "child's steak" would go to "child'steak" (the "s"'s would match). Then, it matches all full words (`(\b\S+\b)`), followed by an end of string (`$`) or a number of spaces (`\s+`), the whole repeated more than once.

I tried it like this and it worked well:

```
var s = "here here here     here is ahi-ahi ahi-ahi ahi-ahi joe's joe's joe's joe's joe's the result result     result";
print( s.replace( /(\b\S+\b)(($|\s+)\1)+/g, "$1"))         
--> here is ahi-ahi joe's the result
```

Comment: I'm having trouble rewriting this into PHP, it's vital I get a single copy of the matched duplicate replacing each occurrence of duplicates/triplicates etc.  So far I have: preg_replace('/(^|\s+)(\S+)(($|\s+)\2)+/im', '$0', $string);

Comment: This is the best answer. I just made a tweak to that by adding `\b` to the end like so: `/(^|\s+)(\S+)(($|\s+)\2)+\b/g, "$1$2")` This will then work for situations like this: `the the string String string stringing the the along the the string` will become `the string stringing the along the string` Notice `string stringing`. It gets matched with your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression it fits for all repeated words cases:

```
\b(\w+)\s+\1(?:\s+\1)*\b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
\b(\w+)(?:\W+\1\b)+
```

This pattern can be used to match all duplicated word groups in sentences. :)

Here is a sample util function written in java 17, which replaces all duplications with the first occurrence:

```java
    public String removeDuplicates(String input) {
        var regex = "\\b(\\w+)(?:\\W+\\1\\b)+";
        var pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        var matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            input = input.replaceAll(matcher.group(), matcher.group(1));
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To find duplicate words that have no leading or trailing non whitespace character(s) other than a word character(s), you can use whitespace boundaries on the left and on the right making use of [lookarounds](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

The pattern will have a match in:

- Paris in `the the` spring.
- Not `that that` is related.

The pattern will **not** have a match in:

- This is $word word

---

```
(?<!\S)(\w+)\s+\1(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert not a non whitespace char to the left of the current location
- `(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1 or more word characters
- `\s+` Match 1 or more whitespace characters (note that this can also match a newline)
- `\1` Backreference to match the same as in group 1
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert not a non whitespace char to the right of the current location

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ceNdT0/1).

---

To find 2 or more duplicate words:

```
(?<!\S)(\w+)(?:\s+\1)+(?!\S)
```

- This part of the pattern `(?:\s+\1)+` uses a non capture group to repeat 1 or more times matching 1 or more whitespace characters followed by the backreference to match the same as in group 1.

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/XrCfPf/1).

---

**Alternatives without using lookarounds**

You could also make use of a leading and trailing alternation *matching* either a whitespace char or assert the start/end of the string.

Then use a capture group 1 for the value that you want to get, and use a second capture group with a backreference `\2` to match the repeated word.

Matching 2 duplicate words:

```
(?:\s|^)((\w+)\s+\2)(?:\s|$)
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/QsDHfb/1).

Matching 2 or more duplicate words:

```
(?:\s|^)((\w+)(?:\s+\2)+)(?:\s|$)
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQdwo5/1).

Answer (score 0):

I think another solution would be to use [named capture groups and backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html) like this:

```
.* (?<mytoken>\w+)\s+\k<mytoken> .*/
```

OR

```
.*(?<mytoken>\w{3,}).+\k<mytoken>.*/
```

[image: Kotlin logo] Kotlin:

```kotlin
val regex = Regex(""".* (?<myToken>\w+)\s+\k<myToken> .*""")
val input = "This is a test test data"
val result = regex.find(input)
println(result!!.groups["myToken"]!!.value)
```

[image: Java logo] Java:

```java
var pattern = Pattern.compile(".* (?<myToken>\\w+)\\s+\\k<myToken> .*");
var matcher = pattern.matcher("This is a test test data");
var isFound = matcher.find();
var result = matcher.group("myToken");
System.out.println(result);
```

[image: JavaScript logo] JavaScript:

```js
const regex = /.* (?<myToken>\w+)\s+\k<myToken> .*/;
const input = "This is a test test data";
const result = regex.exec(input);
console.log(result.groups.myToken);

// OR

const regex = /.* (?<myToken>\w+)\s+\k<myToken> .*/g;
const input = "This is a test test data";
const result = [...input.matchAll(regex)];
console.log(result[0].groups.myToken);
```

---

All the above detect the `test` as the duplicate word.
Tested with Kotlin *1.7.0-Beta*, Java *11*, Chrome and Firefox *100*.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in case you want case-insensitive checking for duplicate words.

```
(?i)\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\b
```

Comment: Using the case-insensitive pattern modifier is no use for your pattern.  There are no letter ranges for the flag to impact.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of the accepted answer and adds no value to the page.  Please consider removing this answer to reduce page bloat.