# Regex: word boundary but for white space, beginning of line or end of line only

Tags: regex

I am looking for some word boundary to cover those 3 cases:

1. beginning of string
2. end of string
3. white space

Is there something like that since \b covers also -,/ etc.?

Would like to replace \b in this pattern by something described above:

```
(\b\d*\sx\s|\b\d*x|\b)
```

Comment: Does `[\s^$]` do what you need? Also, it may help to tell what regex engine you're using.

Comment: @LarsH: the caret and dollar in the square brackets as shown are simple characters, not metacharacters.

Comment: Actually I believe that inside the square brackets, the ^ is just a different metacharacter. It negates a value, so [^f] will match anything EXCEPT "f"

Comment: @gnomed: Only if it's the first character inside the brackets.

Comment: @Jonathan, ok. I thought maybe that was the case... couldn't remember.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, so your real question is:

How do I match a unit, optionally preceded by a quantity, but only if there is either nothing or a space right before the match?

Use

```
 (?<!\S)\b(?:\d+\s*x\s*)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*ml\b
```

**Explanation**

`(?<!\S)`: Assert that it's impossible to match a non-space character before the match.

`\b`: Match a word boundary

`(?:\d+\s*x\s*)?`: Optionally match a quantifier (integers only)

`\d+(?:\.\d+)?`: Match a number (decimals optional)

`\s*ml\b`: Match `ml`, optionally preceded by whitespace.

Comment: Maybe if you could explain what you really want to do. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have posted my pattern above, just wanted to replace \b by this limited word boundry if possible

Comment: This is not what "explaining what problem you're trying to solve" means. What do you need the regex *for*? Show some examples of what you're trying to match, what you're trying *not* to match, and possibly any further "rules" the matches have to follow.

Comment: looks nice but not matching floats i.e. 1.50 ml

Comment: OK, changed the regex to accomodate that. You should know and state your requirements clearly - you hadn't said anything about floats before...

Answer (score 28):

Try replacing `\b` with `(?:^|\s|$)`

That means

```
(
  ?: don't consider this group a match
  ^   match beginning of line
  |   or
  \s  match whitespace
  |   or
  $   match end of line
)
```

Works for me in Python and JavaScript.

Comment: In Javascript, the outer group includes everything, including the non capturing group. Using exec() I can get the 2nd group, which excludes the non capturing group, but how can I use this in replace() in Javascript?

Comment: Works perfectly in .net - thanks! That is exactly what I'd been looking for. (The regex I'm trying to match between whitespace/beginning/end of line is different, but the "match whitespace or beginning or end of line" behavior is exactly what I was looking for.)

Comment: @FernandoCamargo I am trying to figure out the same thing using replace() in javascript

Comment: @Kdawgwilk did you find a solution? I'm facing exactly the same problem

Comment: @Jordane I will see if I can find it tomorrow and I'll let you know

Comment: This also matches the whitespace before and after it. How can i make it only match the word and not including the white spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Boundaries that you get with `\b` are **not** whitespace sensitive.  They are complicated conditional assertions related to the transition between `\w\W` or `\W\w`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173) for how to write your anchor more precisely, so that you can deal with whitespace the way you want.