# How to match the beginning of a String in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match an HTML file:

If the file starts with spaces and then an end tag `</sometag>`, `return true`.

Else `return false`.

I used the `"(\\s)*</(\\w)*>.*"`, but it doesn't match `\n    </p>\n   </blockquote> ...`.

Comment: @Gabe I thought it matches newlines. See here http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html. \s A whitespace character, short for [ \t\n\x0b\r\f]

Comment: @JackWM: You're right; it's `.` that doesn't necessarily match `\n`. See the `DOTALL` mode.

Comment: I think you should consider reading this SO answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026115/regex-word-boundary-but-for-white-space-beginning-of-line-or-end-of-line-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gabe's help. Gabe is correct. The `.` doesn't match `\n` by default. I need to set the `DOTALL` mode on.

To do it, add the `(?s)` to the beginning of the regex, i.e. `(?s)(\\s)*</(\\w)*>.*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\s)*</(\\w)*>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
return m.lookingAt();
```

It just checks if the string starts with the pattern, rather than checking the whole string matches the pattern.