# PCRE(php) Is it possible to check if sequence of numbers contains only unique number for that sequence?

Tags: php, regex

Assuming I have a set of numbers (from 1 to 22) divided by some trivial delimiters (comma, point, space, etc). I need to make sure that this set of numbers does not contain any repetition of the same number. Examples:

```
1,14,22,3 // good
1,12,12,3 // not good
```

Is it possible to do via regular expression?

I know it's easy to do using just php, but I really wander how to make it work with regex.

Comment: possible, yes. desirable, probably not.

Comment: Whether or not it's possible, using a regex to do this is a lousy idea.

Comment: [But for the curious, this is a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words)

Comment: @hobbs Maybe, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with wondering how one could do so if they wanted to.

Comment: here is what I'm trying to get: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ3nZ0/1), so the regex would extract valid numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could achieve this through regex via negative looahead.

```
^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)\d+(?:,\d+)+$
```

- `(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)` Negative lookahead at the start asserts that the there wouldn't be a repeated number present in the match. `\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b` matches the repeated number.
- `\d+` matches one or more digits.
- `(?:,\d+)+` One or more occurances of `,` , one or more digits.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end .

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tD9pA4/2)

**OR**

Regex for the numbers separated by space, dot, comma as delimiters.

```
^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)\d+(?:([.\s,])\d+)(?:\2\d+)*$
```

`(?:([.\s,])\d+)` capturing group inside this non-capturing group helps us to check for following  delimiters are of the same type. ie, the above regex won't match the strings like `2,3 5.6`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tD9pA4/3)

Comment: Without any kind of explanation, this answer is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks Avinash Raj, not sure I've get it. Currently I have an agly one like this: ^([,.:\s]+(1\d{1}|2[0-2]{1}|\d{1})[,.:\s]+(1\d{1}|2[0-2]{1}|\d{1})[,.:\s]+(1\d{1}|2[0-2]{1}|\d{1}))$ How would I apply your solution to this one? or I just start over..

Comment: @madbreaks I've used the same online tool

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!.*?(\b\d+)\W+\1\b)\d+(\W+\d+)*$
```

- **Negative lookahead** `(?!.*?(\b\d+)\W+\1\b)` avoids the match when 2 similar numbers appear one after another separated by 1 or more non-word characters.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM0uW4/4)

Comment: Fails for even `1,2,1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that fit my current need:

```
^(?>(?!\2\b|\3\b)(1\d{1}|2[0-2]{1}|\d{1}+)[,.; ]+)(?>(?!\1\b|\3\b)(1\d{1}|2[0-2]{1}|\d{1}+)[,.; ]+)(?>(?!\1\b|\2\b)(1\d{1}|2[0-2]{1}|\d{1}+))$
```

It returns all the sequences with unique numbers divided by one or more separator and also limit the number itself from 1 to 22, allowing only 3 numbers in the sequence.

See [working example](https://regex101.com/r/bO9hN5/1)

Yet, it's not perfect, but work fine! Thanks a lot to everyone who gave me a hand on this!

Comment: Well, that's more requirements now... Here's a [shorther one](https://regex101.com/r/bO9hN5/2) that might work for you: `^(?>([1-9]|1\d|2[0-2])\b(?!.*?\b\1\b)[ .,;]*){3}$`