# Regular Expression for Searching Duplicate Word in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to find the repeating word from a given String.
I want to have a regular expression to find every occurrence of a word.
for example `"I want to eat apple. apple is a fruit"`.

the regular expression should find out word `"apple"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words

Comment: So do you have tried any thing for figuring your problem out?

Comment: why you want to use regex ?

Comment: Regex is not the right way to do this. Use `String#split()` and then add the strings to a `Set`.

Comment: @TheLostMind : I already tried this using a java code...FYI please have look http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88234/removing-and-counting-repeated-strings...But trying a regular expression...

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti - Regex is not the right way of approaching this problem.. regex was not designed for cases like this. You might come up with a regex, but it will most probably break somewhere.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov : I had a look at it, its not the result...its says no match ..

Comment: To be clear solving this with a regex is only possible in theory, but in practice the complexity becomes too high too quickly with the string length. So a possible approach consists to store positions in the string for each different words in a data structure.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : yes I agree with you...it would be complex...I had given a try with code...I thought of giving a try with regex...

Comment: @Saif : I have given a try with code, wanted to try with regex..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to match all the duplicate words in a line.

```
(\\b\\w+\\b)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)        // matches duplicates only in a single line
```

**Edit:** If you want to match duplicates in multiple lines you can use:

```
(\\b\\w+\\b)(?=[\\s\\S]*\\b\\1\\b)  // or the above regex with DOTALL flag
```

See [demo for single line](https://regex101.com/r/tC0tS5/7) and [demo for multiple lines](https://regex101.com/r/tC0tS5/8)

Comment: There is a little issue in this expression. It does not highlight the last instance of each matched word. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This works for multiple repetitions and multiline:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w+)\\b(?=.*\\b(\\1)\\b)", Pattern.DOTALL);

    String s = "I want to eat apple. apple is a fruit.\r\n I really want fruit.";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("at: " + m.start(1) + " " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("    " + m.start(2) + " " + m.group(2));
    }
```

It outputs:

```
at: 0 I
    41 I
at: 2 want
    50 want
at: 14 apple
    21 apple
at: 32 fruit
    55 fruit
```

Comment: Your regex will consume text between duplicates which will prevent reusing it to find other duplicates like `eat apple eat apple`

Comment: It will not be much more complex. All you need to do is prevent consuming which can be done by look-ahead mechanism.

Comment: @Pshemo: even with a lookahead, this kind of pattern will crash (or take too much times) with few lines of text.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, I also don't like regex (because of its inefficiency like in case of this one greediness, and mistakes like lack of support for `.` to match line separators), but since OP is asking for regex it let him have it (everyone has right to do their own mistakes). I hope that OP will test this approach and will figure out that upvoted comments ware upvoted for a reason.

Comment: @Pshemo: I appreciate your support. I have already given a try by writing a piece of java code...I thought a giving a try with regex...As I m not the expert of regex..asking for the help...here is my code ...Its not doing http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88234/removing-and-counting-repeated-strings

Comment: @DanielSperry "*@karthik manchala got it perfectly*" actually it is very far from perfect. That solution will not support multiple lines, and in look-ahead it will try to traverse till end of line, even if it will find correct match.

Comment: @Pshemo.. I dont know if it is perfect.. but updated my answer for finding duplicates in multiple lines :)

Comment: @Pshemo, thanks for your comments I think the answer looks a lot better now. And karthik manchala, good call with the lookahead!

Comment: Yes it does, but please make `.*` reluctant instead of greedy by adding `?` right after it. Don't make regex search for *last* repetition of word.

Answer (score 1):

This approach strips out anything that's not alphanumeric or whitespace, splits on the white space and creates a `Map` of the results.

```
Stream.of("I? want.... to eat apple    eat apple.      apple, is! a fruit".split("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+"))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
```

Result:

```
a=[a], apple=[apple, apple, apple], fruit=[fruit], want=[want], eat=[eat, eat], I=[I], is=[is], to=[to]
```

Comment: Instead of collecting the word itself (that is not very interesting), you should collect the indexes of these words in the string. Note too that instead of replacing special characters and split by spaces, you should search the string with for example `[\\p{L}\\p{N}]+`.

Comment: Updated for the split regex.

Comment: @SteveChaloner : I m not able resolve the Stream and Collectors.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti they're from Java 8