# javascript regex to match double word gives different result everytime

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the output from my browsers console. This regex checks for doubled_words, looks for occurrences of words (strings containing 1 or more letters) followed by whitespace followed by the same word.

```
var reg=/([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2800-\uFFFD]+)\s+\1/gi;
undefined
reg.test("sdfs sdsdf")
true
reg.test("sdfs sdsdf")
false
```

the result is true alternate times, why is this weird behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression For Consecutive Duplicate Words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is due to use of `global` flag. Remove it

```
var reg=/([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2800-\uFFFD]+)\s+\1/;
```

Using `g` causes regex state (`lastIndex` value) to be remembered across multipel calls to `test` or `exec` methods.

[Check this official reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) Read the **Description** section.