# PostgreSQL: .csv regex - test for repeating substrings within a string (digits)

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring

### Introduction:

I have the following scenario in PostgreSQL whereby I want to perform some data validation on a .csv string prior to inserting it into a table (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=233dfed72f5fe0c32902a442d5f979a5)).

I've managed to get a regex (in a `CHECK` constraint) which disallows spaces within strings (e.g. "`12  34`") and also disallows preceding zeros ("`00343`").

Now, the icing on the cake would be if I could use regular expressions to disallow strings which contain a repeat of an integer - i.e. if a sequence `\d+` matched another `\d+` within the same string.

Is this beyond the capacities of regular expressions?

My table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  data TEXT NOT NULL,
  
  CONSTRAINT d_csv_only_ck 
    CHECK (data ~ '^([ ]*([1-9]\d*)+[ ]*)(,[ ]*([1-9]\d*)+[ ]*)*$')

);
```

And I can populate it as follows:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
('992,1005,1007,992,456,456,1008'),  -- want to make this line unnacceptable - repeats!
('44,1005,1110'), 
('13,  44  ,  1005,  10078  '),  -- acceptable - spaces before and after integers   
('11,1203,6666'),
('1,11,99,2222'),
('3435'),             
('  1234    '); -- acceptable
```

But:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('23432, 3433   ,00343, 567'); -- leading 0 - unnacceptable
```

fails (as it should), and also fails (again, as it should)

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('12  34');  -- spaces within numbers - unnacceptable
```

### The question:

However, if you notice the first string, it has repeats of `992`and `456`.

I would like to be able to match these.

All of these rules do not have to be in the same regex - I can use a second `CHECK` constraint.

I would like to know if what I am asking is possible using Regular Expressions?

I did find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36127536/470530) which appears to go some (all?) of the way to solving my issue, but I'm afraid it's beyond my skillset to get it to work - I've included a small test at the bottom of the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=233dfed72f5fe0c32902a442d5f979a5).

Please let me know should you require any further information.

p.s. as an aside, I'm not very experienced with regexes and I would welcome any input on my basic one above.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do but I wonder why? Why are adding the validation at the database layer? Could you possibly have it in the code that manages the database? What kind of data is it?

Comment: From the looks of it, this is simply a RegEx match problem.

Comment: @ErionOmeri - yes, it's a matching problem, but within the input string and not simply matching a given string literal that's already known with the input!

Comment: You might need to use regex “Look Ahead” to see if the string repeats. I am not sure if PostreSQL supports that in its implementation. You could create a function to make things a lot easier, but I would do this code, if at all.

Comment: PostgreSQL does have [very sophisticated](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-matching.html) regex capabilites! Faleminderit for your input!

Comment: Lol, that’s awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PostegreSQL regex [does not support backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751376/postgresql-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-backreference-number?lq=1), you cannot apply this restriction because you would need a negative lookahead with a backreference in it.

Have a look at this *PCRE* regex:

```js
^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b) *[1-9]\d* *(?:, *[1-9]\d* *)*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hMihE0/2).
*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)` - no same two numbers as whole word allowed anywhere in the string
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `[1-9]\d*` - a non-zero digit and then any zero or more digits
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `(?:, *[1-9]\d* *)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `, *` - comma and zero or more spaces
  - `[1-9]\d*` - a non-zero digit and then any zero or more digits
  - `*` - zero or more spaces
- `$` - end of string.

Even if you replace `\b` with `\y` (PostgreSQL regex word boundaries) in the PostgreSQL code, it won't work due to the drawback mentioned at the top of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I already upvoted your contribution which I reference in my question, so I hope you won't mind a direct question! If you look [here](https://regex101.com/r/fu3K60/1), your regex does what I want with INTs, it seems to "get confused" with alphabetical strings for some reason? Could you also provide a brief breakdown of what the bits do? Ideally, I'd like to know "how to fish..."!

Comment: @Vérace I do not quite understand what confusion you noticed here. What do you mean?

Comment: 456, 897, 456 - is in white - a match on 456? asfdasdf adsfas ,adfas also in white - no match there?

Comment: @Vérace `456, 897, 456` should not match, there are two repeating numbers. `asfdasdf adsfas ,adfas` has no numbers and should not match.

Comment: Ah... OK, I was "inverting" them - if I want to reverse the "polarity" - i.e. make the white ones coloured and the coloured ones white - what do I have to do? (final question - then I'll upvote and mark as correct - and dziękuję). Trying to understand!... :-)

Comment: @Vérace A very crude way to reverse a pattern that matches the whole string is to use `^(?!pattern).*` / `^(?!pattern)`. So, in your case, `^(?!(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b) *[1-9]\d* *(?:, *[1-9]\d* *)*$).*` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fu3K60/2)).

Comment: I upvoted your answer as helpful - and it does answer the question. Would you be able to look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4253e80e03ed2151ed774495687ba2d4) and tell me if it's a PostgreSQL problem or is there something I'm missing? If so, I'll mark your input as correct... sorry about the messing around. I'll mark it correct anyway  - it's puzzling me because normally PostgreSQL is **very** standards compliant and I'm wondering if it's a PostgreSQL problem? Thanks for any input...

Comment: @Vérace Sorry, I forgot that PostegreSQL regex [does not support backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751376/postgresql-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-backreference-number?lq=1). I updated the answer.

Comment: Ah, well, thanks for your input anyway! I can do it in various other ways - would have been nice to do it in DDL - I'm a big believer in putting as much as possible into the DDL code as soon as possible - your db is your last line of defence for your data and the stronger you can make it, the better, but I did learn a bit! Jeszcze raz dzięki...