# Remove multiples of character sequence from string

Tags: python, regex

If I had a string like so:

```
my_string = 'this is is is is a string'
```

How would I remove the multiple `is`s so that only one will show?

This string could contain any number of `is` in there such as

```
my_string = 'this is is a string'
other_string = 'this is is is is is is is is a string'
```

A regex solution would be possible I suppose however I'm not sure how to go about it. Thanks.

Comment: Count the occurance of "is" string and keep on deleting duplicate strings whenever counter >1

Comment: @MohitSharma Surely there must be a more efficient solution?

Comment: You want to remove only `is` or any duplicate occurrences? Like `'this is is is is a a a string string'`  to `'this is a string'`.

Comment: @PSidhu most of the time you should put your attempt

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words.

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Regex to the rescue!

```
((\b\w+\b)\s*\2\s*)+
# capturing group
# inner capturing group
# ... consisting of a word boundary, at least ONE word character and another boundary
# followed by whitespaces
# and the formerly captured group (aka the inner group)
# the whole pattern needs to be present at least once, but can be there
# multiple times
```

#### Python Code

```
import re

string = """
this is is is is is is is is a string
and here is another another another another example
"""
rx = r'((\b\w+\b)\s*\2\s*)+'

string = re.sub(rx, r'\2 ', string)
print string
# this is a string
# and here is another example
```

#### Demos

See a demo for this <kbd>[approach on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bZ9jW6/1)</kbd> as well as on <kbd>[ideone.com](http://ideone.com/gD64V9)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby
a = 'this is is is is a a a string string a a a'
print ' '.join(word for word, _ in groupby(a.split(' ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

```
my_string = 'this is is a string'
other_string = 'this is is is is is is is is a string'
def getStr(s):
    res = []
    [res.append(i) for i in s.split() if i not in res]
    return ' '.join(res)

print getStr(my_string)
print getStr(other_string)
```

Output:

```
this is a string
this is a string
```

**UPDATE** The regex way to attack it:

```
import re
print ' '.join(re.findall(r'(?:^|)(\w+)(?:\s+\1)*', other_string))
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nT4vG0/1)

Comment: Your non-regex approach will remove *any* subsequent occurrences of any word in the string: `getStr('this string is a string')` --> `'this string is a'`. While the question is unclear, I think this is probably not what the OP has in mind.

Comment: You are right. It's good for the OP's question. The regex way is more reliable I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to remove all duplicates after one another, you can try

```
l = my_string.split()
tmp = [l[0]]
for word in l:
    if word != tmp[-1]:
        tmp.append(word)
s = ''
for word in tmp:
    s += word + ' '
my_string = s
```

of course, if you want it smarter than this, it is going to be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

For oneliners:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> my_string = 'this is is a string'
>>> " ".join([k for k, g in itertools.groupby(my_string.split())])
'this is a string'
```