# Regular Expression For Consecutive Duplicate Bigrams

Tags: regex, r, gsub

My question is a direct extension of this earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words) about detecting consecutive words (unigrams) in a string.

In the previous question,

> Not **that that** is related

could be detected via this regex: `\b(\w+)\s+\1\b`

Here, I want to detect consecutive bigrams (pairs of words):

> are blue **and then and then** very bright

Ideally, I also want to know how to replace the detected pattern (duplicate) by a single element, so as to obtain in the end:

> are blue and then very bright

(for this application, if it matters, I am using `gsub` in R)

Comment: There can be edge cases here... What is your exact criteria? Try [`(\b.+\b)\1\b`](https://regex101.com/r/eF5tF2/3). `gsub("(\\b.+\\b)\\1\\b", "\\1", s, perl=T)`.

Comment: thank you for your interest in my question. What do you mean by `edge cases`?

Comment: it seems that your proposed solution works well... By `edge cases` do you mean that in some situations it could behave unexpectedly?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution will not work [in all cases](https://regex101.com/r/lJ5wC6/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [Still does not work...](https://regex101.com/r/jL7uI7/1)

Comment: The thing is that if you have longer and shorter repeating substrings, a lazy matching pattern can be used. It depends. See [`(\b.+?\b)\1\b`](https://regex101.com/r/eF5tF2/4) - check how the matches differ by removing and adding the question mark. Please precise.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew when I remove the question mark it captures longer repeated patterns. In my case I am only interested in detecting repeated bigrams, so I'll leave the question mark.

Comment: One last comment: if your repeating substrings span across multiple *lines*, and you will use a `perl=T`, add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern. If you do not use `perl=T`, do not add `(?s)` as in TRE, `.` matches any character including a newline.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok thanks. I don't think my input text spans across multiple lines but I will check. I am leaving now but I will accept your answer when I come back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point here is that in some cases, there will be repeating substrings that include shorter repeated substrings. So, to match the longer ones, you would use

```
(\b.+\b)\1\b
```

(see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH9zO2/2)) and for those to find shorter substrings, I'd rely on *lazy dot matching*:

```
(\b.+?\b)\1\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH9zO2/1). The replacement string will be `\1` - the backreference to the captured part matched first with the grouping construct `(...)`.

You need a PCRE regex to make it work, since there are documented issues with matching multiple word boundaries with [`gsub`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) (so, add `perl=T` argument).

> POSIX 1003.2 mode of gsub and gregexpr does not work correctly with repeated word-boundaries (e.g., `pattern = "\b"`). Use `perl = TRUE` for such matches (but that may not work as expected with non-ASCII inputs, as the meaning of ‘word’ is system-dependent).

Note that in case your repeated substrings can span across multiple lines, you can use the PCRE regex with the DOTALL modifier `(?s)` at the start of the pattern (so that a `.` could also match a newline symbol).

So, the R code would look like

```
gsub("(?s)(\\b.+\\b)\\1\\b", "\\1", s, perl=T)
```

or

```
gsub("(?s)(\\b.+?\\b)\\1\\b", "\\1", s, perl=T)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/SiKl4e):

```
text <- "are blue and then and then more and then and then more very bright"
gsub("(?s)(\\b.+?\\b)\\1\\b", "\\1", text, perl=T) ## shorter repeated substrings
## [1] "are blue and then more and then more very bright"
gsub("(?s)(\\b.+\\b)\\1\\b", "\\1", text, perl=T) ## longer repeated substrings
## [1] "are blue and then and then more very bright"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following RegEx:

```
(\b.+?\b)\1\b
```

The RegEx will capture a word boundary, followed by the data and then another word boundary. The `\1` will refer to what was captured, and select that again. It will then check for a word boundary the the end to prevent `a and` and `z zoo` from being selected

As for the replace, use `\1`. This will contain the data from the **`1st` Capture Group** (the first part of the bigram), and that first part will be used to replace the whole thing.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/fP8bA2/1)</kbd>

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you were the first to answer via your comments. The current answer is almost exactly the same thing you proposed (only difference I can see is `\b` at the end), so if you post an answer I will accept it since you were the first

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually no, there is not even a difference between what you proposed in your comments and the current answer. So if you post an answer I will definitely accept it

Comment: @Antoine: It is ok, I do not like posting duplicates of existing answers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes but it is even worse than leaving a thread unclosed. I would feel uncomfortable accepting another answer since you were the first. Too bad I cannot accept a comment as an answer

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You did answer first, I'll delete this if you want...?

Comment: This is embarassing. I have never been in such a situation.

Comment: guys, I am not an expert about SO rules but think it is fine to leave both contributions. However, since @WiktorStribiżew answered first I will accept his answer if he provides one.

Comment: Ok, I will write a comprehensive R-related answer. No need to delete this one.

Comment: great I think this settles it