# Regex with two consecutive (identical or not) matches

Tags: php, regex

I've written this regex for a PHP regex function:

```
\[\[.*?\]\]
```

This matches words or phrases between double square brackets. What I'm trying to find now is a regexp that match two or more consecutive (identical or not) matches. I've tried with

```
(\[\[.*?\]\]){2,}
```

and with this workaround: [Regular Expression For Consecutive Duplicate Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words). However, none of them worked. Does anyone has a better idea?

What I'm trying to match is, for example, `[one][two][three]`. The first part of the regexp will match `[one]` and I'm trying to get the entire phrase `[one][two][three]`.

Thanks!

Comment: Try [`(\[\[.*?\]\])\1+`](https://regex101.com/r/oJ7bK1/1). Please provide test strings and expected outputs since the question sounds a bit unclear. How didn't it work? What do you mean by *identical or not matches*?

Comment: Maybe you need [`(\[\[.*?\]\])(?:\s*(?1))+`](https://regex101.com/r/oJ7bK1/3)? Or [`(?:\s*\[\[.*?\]\]){2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/oJ7bK1/4)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What I'm trying to match is, for example, `[one][two][three]`. The first part of the regexp will match `[one]` and I'm trying to get the entire phrase `[one][two][three]`. Is that clearer? Thank you!

Comment: So, your regex works, doesn't it? If you remove 1 bracket from both sides. See [`(\[.*?\]){2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/sP3hL5/1). Or a more elegant: [`(?:\[[^][]*]){2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/sP3hL5/2). Or do you want to capture the first `[one]`? Then use [`(\[[^][]*])(?1)+`](https://regex101.com/r/sP3hL5/3). What is the output *structure* you need? Does any of the above work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My expected output is `[one][two][three]`. Sorry I'm not being clear enough! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove 1 bracket from both sides of your second pattern, it will already work. See [`(\[.*?\]){2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/sP3hL5/1).

A more elegant solution is [`(?:\[[^][]*]){2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/sP3hL5/2). Here, `\[` matches  a `[`, `[^][]*` will match zero or more characters other than `]` and `[` and `]` will match a closing literal `]`.

If you want to capture the first `[one]` into Group 1, use [`(\[[^][]*])(?1)+`](https://regex101.com/r/sP3hL5/3). Here, `(?1)` re-uses Group 1 subpattern (i.e. `\[[^][]*]`).

Here is a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/biJOwC):

```
$re = '~(?:\[[^][]*]){2,}~'; 
$str = "[one][two][three]"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]); // => [one][two][three]
```