# How to proofread PDFs automatically & test them for errors?

Tags: regex, makefile, grep, automated-tests, pdftotext

When using a makefile to generate PDFs from LaTeX or MarkDown with pandoc, how can one automatically check the resulting PDFs for errors, that the code/text editor might not find?

Answer (score 2):

If the errors are known & can be reg-ex'd (such as [duplicate words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words/12309899#12309899)), write those down line-by-line in a file (e.g. called `CHECKS`). Then, use the following commands in the makefile:

```
pdftotext file.pdf - | \  # sends content of PDF to stdout & pipes it into...
grep \
    --color \             # highlights errors in stdout
    --ignore-case \
    --extended-regexp \
    --file=CHECKS         # contains the error patterns
```

Appended to the make target of the PDF, this IMHO helps to prevent particularly repetitive errors.

PS: Summarised from a [German blog post](http://edit.hypotheses.org/399). Real-life [example here](https://github.com/katrinleinweber/PhD-thesis/blob/doctor/makefile#L97).