# Removing consecutive duplicate words in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to write a function that removes consecutive duplicate words within a string.   It's vital that one any matches found by the regular expression remains.   In other words...

> A very very very dirty dog

should become...

> A very dirty dog

I have a regular expression that seems to work well ([based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words))

```
(\b\S+\b)(($|\s+)\1)+
```

However I'm not sure how to use preg_replace (or if there's a better function) to implement this.   Right now I have it deleting all matching repeated words without leaving one copy of the word intact.    Can I parse a variable or special instruction to it to keep a match ?

I have this currently...

```
$string=preg_replace('/(\b\S+\b)(($|\s+)\1)+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Note there is no point using the `$` in the alternation as `$\1` will never match (you do not even use the multiline modifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a regex like `\b(\S+)(?:\s+\1\b)+` and replace with `$1`:

```
$string=preg_replace('/\b(\S+)(?:\s+\1\b)+/i', '$1', $string);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vhsCpJ/4)

**Details**:

- `\b(\S+)`  - Group 1 capturing one or more non-whitespace symbols that are preceded with a word boundary (maybe `\b(\w+)` would suit better here)
- `(?:\s+\1\b)+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
  - `\1\b` - a backreference to the value stored in Group 1 buffer (the value must be a whole word)

The replacement pattern is `$1`, the replacement backreference that refers to the value stored in Group 1 buffer.

Note that `/i` case insensitive modifier will make `\1` case insensitive, and `I have a dog Dog DOG` will result in `I have a dog`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor!  To clarify, my previous expression was also capturing words with different cases.   So that may be useful for some and worth putting on the record.

Comment: I believe my original regex works with different cased words.  So "very Very very" would also be caught

Comment: Ah ok...  I just tried the working demo and it doesn't seem to do that

Comment: You must add the case insensitive modifier.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with this Wiktor!

Comment: unfortunately works only for Latin alphabet, e.g. try it on phrase  'молоко молоко         хлеб колбаса ' , my php version is 5.6

Comment: @Tebe Use `preg_replace('/\b(\S+)(?:\s+\1\b)+/u', '$1', "молоко молоко хлеб колбаса");`. Also, `'/\b(\p{L}+)(?:\s+\1\b)+/u'` will work, too.

Comment: wow, wow, looks like a black magic. Especially the second  approach in comment.  As far as I understand " u " modifier is used to make it work with unicode. So the universal solution would be preg_replace('/\b(\S+)(?:\s+\1\b)+/iu', '$1', $text)  .  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text ='one one, two three, two';
$result_text = preg_replace("/\b(\w+)\s+\\1\b/i", "$1", $text);
echo "Result Text: ".$result_text; //one, two three, two
?>
```

Try this. It should return one copy intact.

Comment: It is a light version of my solution without more than 1 duplicate word support.