# Is there a way to trim a word from a string if it is a duplicate word and not trim when there is no duplicate word?

Tags: php, string

I need a combination of if statements in which a specific word is occurring twice, then only the first one of these instances needs to be removed.

In my code `$heading_title` is a string to display as a product name.
Now in two cases the heading title uses the same word twice.

```
heading title = Same Same words used
```

or

```
heading title = Words Words are the same
```

or

```
heading title = correct words used
```

Now in the case of Same and Words I want the string to be trimmed so it will display like:

```
Same words used and Words are the same
```

the last heading title is ok. Is there a way to accomplish that?

I tried some answers about trim here on Stack, but I cannot get it to work, so only the initial code is pasted.

```
<h1 class="heading-title" itemprop="name"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
```

Result is that for most products it is ok, but in those two cases where the first word is the same, it doesn't look nice for a product name..

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: https://regex101.com/r/V0wL5m/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing consecutive duplicate words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602305/removing-consecutive-duplicate-words-in-a-string)

Comment: @Jay if you're still around, that dupe target is more relevant^

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier since someone reopened it I don't have the option of duping it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to solve this using regex. What I got from your question, you would like to remove duplicate words from the start of the string. A pattern like this would help:

```
^(\w+)\s(\1)(?=\s)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V0wL5m/1)

Code Sample:

```
$re = '/^(\w+)\s(\1)(?=\s)/m';
$str = 'Words Words are the same
correct words used
Same words used and Words are the same
Same words used and Words are the same Same';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped as a constructive answer, i couldn't get around with the "suggested answers", you clarified it with exactly my problem. Now my problem is solved.