# How to replace multiple &nbsp and whitespace with one &nbsp and shrink whitespace only chunks to a space?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following custom text and HTML:

```
$text = "<p>Hello World!&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Javascript development&nbsp;PHP Developer&nbsp;</p>";
```

How can I change that text, using regular expressions, into the following:

```
"<p>Hello World!&nbsp;Javascript development&nbsp;PHP Developer</p>"
```

**Code:**

```
$text = "<p>Hello World!&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Javascript development&nbsp;PHP Developer&nbsp;</p>";
$result = preg_replace("/(&nbsp;)+/", "&nbsp;", $text);
echo $result;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code (in the question, not as a link!). What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Try `preg_replace(["/\s*&nbsp;(?:\s*&nbsp;)*\s*/", "/\s+/"], ['&nbsp;',' '], $text);` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/X5cRA))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42602323/10230696

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your regexp partially works. How to add such a rule that at the beginning and at the end of the text there was no `&nbsp` ?

Comment: `preg_replace(['/^((?:&nbsp;|\s)+)|(?1)$/', '/\s*&nbsp;(?:\s*&nbsp;)*\s*/', '/\s+/'], ['', '&nbsp;',' '], trim($text));`, see https://3v4l.org/U4faU

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @AndreasHunter [Posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55472840/3832970) as an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42602323/10230696 has nothing to do with the current question since it is not about shrinking multiple consecutive single word to one occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
$find = ['/^((?:&nbsp;|\s)+)|(?1)$/', '/\s*&nbsp;(?:\s*&nbsp;)*\s*/', '/\s+/'];
$replace = ['', '&nbsp;',' '];
$text = preg_replace($find, $replace, trim($text));
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/U4faU).

**Details**

- `'/^((?:&nbsp;|\s)+)|(?1)$/'` => `''` removes `&nbsp;` and whitespaces at the start/end of string (`(?1)` here just recurses `(?:&nbsp;|\s)+` and is here to make the pattern a bit shorter)
- `'/\s*&nbsp;(?:\s*&nbsp;)*\s*/'` => `'&nbsp;'` replaces all sequences of whitespace and `&nbsp;` with at least one `&nbsp;` with one `&nbsp;`
- `'/\s+/'` => `' '` replaces 1+ whitespaces with 1 regular space.

Answer (score 2):

Your input text contains spaces after most `&nbsp;` which your regex does not account for. You can use `\s*` to allow for zero or more spaces before and after each non-breakable space HTML entity.

```php
$result = preg_replace('/(\s*&nbsp;\s*)+/', '&nbsp;', $text);
```