# Removing duplicates words from a string

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have a string like:

> Hello how how how are are you you?
>
> I love cookies cookies, apples and pancakes pancakes.

I wish for an output:

> Hello how are you?
>
> I love cookies, apples and pancakes.

Till now I have coded:

```js
String[] s = input.split(" ");
String prev = s[0];
String ans = prev + " ";

for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {

    if (!prev.equals(s[i])) {
        prev = s[i];
        ans += prev + " ";
    }
}

System.out.println(ans);
```

I get outputs as:

> Hello how are you you?
>
> I love cookies cookies, apples and pancakes pancakes.

I need some help with the logic for `, . ! ? .`..

Comment: @JBNizet I find your comment rude, the author of the post said he needs help with the logic, meaning he already knows that they are not the same, and since he already knows that it gives problems, suggesting him to debug isn't going to solve the problem

Comment: @JBNizet yes I know `cookies` is not equal to `cookies,`. I need to help with the logic so that my program takes it as the same and adds the one with the punctuation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I eliminate duplicate words from String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770863/how-can-i-eliminate-duplicate-words-from-string-in-java)

Comment: What you need is called _[Tokenization](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/tokenization-1.html)_.

Comment: @TiiJ7, there was a wrong usage of formatting — a code quote style for the text quote.

Comment: @MikeB. So what has bad formatting to do with changes the actual output text? You just duplicated the word "pancakes", making the expected output change, and invalidating the posted answer

Comment: @Ferrybig, yes, it was my fault during the text formatting. Now everything is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `regex` to do this for you. sample code:

```
String regex = "\\b(\\w+)\\b\\s*(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)";
input = input.replaceAll(regex,"");
```

1. `\b`  Matches a word boundary position between a word character and non-word character or position (start / end of string).
2. `\w`  Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
3. `\b`  Matches a word boundary position between a word character and non-word character or position (start / end of string).
4. `\s`  Matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).
5. `*`  Match `0` or more of the preceding token.
6. `(?=`  Matches a group after the main expression without including it in the result.
7. `.`  Matches any character except line breaks.
8. `\1`  Matches the results of capture group #1 in step 2.

**Note: It is important to use word boundaries here to avoid matching partial words.**

Here's a link to regex demo and explaination : [RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/CLTP2j/6)

Comment: can you pls explain the regex pls

Comment: What the - how are we supposed to understand that?

Comment: i added a link to demo and explaination you can modify it there to see & compare results

Comment: Might want to note that as currently written this won't work if contractions are allowed in the input. An input of `can't can't` will result in `'can't`

Answer (score 2):

You should use a secondary variable to store your words without the punctuation.

```java
String[] s = input.split(" ");
String ans = "";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 1; i++) {

    String currentAux = s[i].replaceAll("[,.!?]", "");
    String nextAux = s[i + 1].replaceAll("[,.!?]", "");

    if (nextAux.equals(currentAux)) {
        continue;
    }

    ans += " " + s[i];
}

ans += " " + s[s.length - 1];

System.out.println(ans);
```

Comment: For `"Hello how how how are are you you?"` it returns `Hello how are you`. `?` is missing

Comment: @SandeepRanjan try it again now :)

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think you should add colon and semicolon in your calls to `replaceAll` because sentences like `"I had a huge meal meal; however, I I am already hungry again again."` will not be handled correctly - `meal` will appear twice.

Comment: @D.B. we cal add a lot of symbols, the ones i used are the ones requested in the end of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `java.util.StringTokenizer` to tokenize the words. Make sure to set the delimiters to split the words. In your case they are spaces, commas and full stops. This can help you to split the words without the punctuation marks. Then you can compare the previous token with the current and if they are equal you can ignore it.

You can try this code snippet:

```java
String s = "I love cookies cookies, apples and pancakes pancakes.";

StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, " ,.", true);

List<String> duplicateRemovedTokenList = new LinkedList<>();

String prevToken = null;

while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

    String currentToken = tokenizer.nextToken();

    if (currentToken.equals(" ")) {
        duplicateRemovedTokenList.add(currentToken);
        continue;
    }

    if (!currentToken.equals(prevToken)) {
        duplicateRemovedTokenList.add(currentToken);
        prevToken = currentToken;
    }
}

String duplicateRemovedString = StringUtils.join(duplicateRemovedTokenList, "");
```

Comment: This has a few problems, it adds extra spaces and doesn't work with inputs like `"I love cookies, cookies, apples and pancakes pancakes."` (note the extra comma after the first `cookies`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a one liner, here is a Java 8 based solution

```
Stream.of(input.split(" ")).distinct().reduce((a, b) -> a + " " + b).orElse("")
```