# Python Dataframe: Remove duplicate words in the same cell within a column in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Below shows a column with data I have and another column with the de-duplicated data I want.

[image]

I honestly don't even know how to start doing this in Python code.  I've read a couple of posts on this in R, but not in Python.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're looking to get rid of consecutive duplicates *only*, this should suffice:

```
df['Desired'] = df['Current'].str.replace(r'\b(\w+)(\s+\1)+\b', r'\1')
df

           Current          Desired
0       Racoon Dog       Racoon Dog
1          Cat Cat              Cat
2  Dog Dog Dog Dog              Dog
3  Rat Fox Chicken  Rat Fox Chicken
```

**Details**

```
\b        # word boundary
(\w+)     # 1st capture group of a single word
( 
\s+       # 1 or more spaces
\1        # reference to first group 
)+        # one or more repeats
\b
```

<sub>Regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2823037/4909087).</sub>

---

To remove non-consecutive duplicates, I'd suggest a solution involving the `OrderedDict` data structure:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

df['Desired'] = (df['Current'].str.split()
                              .apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())
                              .str.join(' '))
df

           Current          Desired
0       Racoon Dog       Racoon Dog
1          Cat Cat              Cat
2  Dog Dog Dog Dog              Dog
3  Rat Fox Chicken  Rat Fox Chicken
```

Comment: The first solution (with regex) does not work, the second solution (with OrderedDict) does work.

Comment: How do you ignore case sensitivity? For example if you had 'Cat cat' and wanted to remove 'cat'?

Comment: @Omega try converting the whole string to lower case first, assuming the result case doesn't matter to you.