# Remove duplicates within a string, but for the entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I want to achieve something like in this post: [Python Dataframe: Remove duplicate words in the same cell within a column in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316783/python-dataframe-remove-duplicate-words-in-the-same-cell-within-a-column-in-pyt), but for the entire dataframe in a efficient way.

My data looks something like this: It is a pandas data frame with a lot of columns. It has comma separated strings where there are a lot of duplicates - and I wish to remove all duplicates within those individual strings.

```
+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
|        Col1        |  Col2   |        Col3         |
+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
| Dog, Dog, Dog      | India   | Facebook, Instagram |
| Dog, Squirrel, Cat | Norway  | Facebook, Facebook  |
| Cat, Cat, Cat      | Germany | Twitter             |
+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Reproducable example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["Dog, Dog, Dog", "Dog, Squirrel, Cat", "Cat, Cat, Cat"],
                     "col2": ["India", "Norway", "Germany"],
                     "col3": ["Facebook, Instagram", "Facebook, Facebook", "Twitter"]})
```

I would like it to transform it to this:

```
+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
|        Col1        |  Col2   |        Col3         |
+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
| Dog                | India   | Facebook, Instagram |
| Dog, Squirrel, Cat | Norway  | Facebook            |
| Cat                | Germany | Twitter             |
+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
for col in ["col1", "col2", "col3"]:
    df[col]=df[col].str.split(", ").map(set).str.join(", ")
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> df

                 col1     col2                 col3
0                 Dog    India  Facebook, Instagram
1  Dog, Cat, Squirrel   Norway             Facebook
2                 Cat  Germany              Twitter
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us do `get_dummies` then `dot`

```
s=df.col1.str.get_dummies(', ')
df['Col1']=s.dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
df
Out[460]: 
                 col1     col2                 col3              Col1
0       Dog, Dog, Dog    India  Facebook, Instagram               Dog
1  Dog, Squirrel, Cat   Norway   Facebook, Facebook  Cat,Dog,Squirrel
2       Cat, Cat, Cat  Germany              Twitter               Cat
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
for col in df.columns.tolist():
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r'\b(\w+)(,+\s+\1)+\b', r'\1')
```