# Delete the repetition of a specific word in a row

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, char

For example I have a string:

```
my_str = 'my example example string contains example some text'
```

What I want to do - delete all duplicates of specific word (only if they goes in a row). Result:

```
my example string contains example some text
```

I tried next code:

```
import re
my_str = re.sub(' example +', ' example ', my_str)
```

or

```
my_str = re.sub('\[ example ]+', ' example ', my_str)
```

But it doesn't work.
I know there are a lot of questions about `re`, but I still can't implement them to my case correctly.

Comment: The best thing you can do is to read a regex tutorial, something basic should suffice.

Comment: A problem that requires the use of word boundaries with dynamic values is not so easy to solve with a regex tutorial. Besides, the [Regular Expression For Consecutive Duplicate Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words) does not contain the Python implementation which is tricky for those who are not familiar with the best practice of using raw string literals for regex patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Solving the general case isn't indeed so easy, but the question is about deleting a *specific* repeated word: `\bexample(?:\s+example)+\b` that is relatively simple, and building it dynamically using a capture group and a back-reference is almost over-engineering if you consider the well known formatted strings widely used in Python. The problem is that the asker lost more time writing a question and waiting for an answer on a topic than reading a tutorial on this topic. Also, he didn't do any search (see the two patterns and the evasive: *"I know there are...blah"*).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That said, my first comment is more an advice than a reproach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a group and quantify it:

```
import re
my_str = 'my example example string contains example some text'
my_str = re.sub(r'\b(example)(?:\s+\1)+\b', r'\1', my_str)
print(my_str) # => my example string contains example some text

# To build the pattern dynamically, if your word is not static
word = "example"
my_str = re.sub(r'(?<!\w)({})(?:\s+\1)+(?!\w)'.format(re.escape(word)), r'\1', my_str)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/i0bi3T)

I added word boundaries as - judging by the spaces in the original code - whole word matches are expected.

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Hdxm5I/2):

- `\b` - word boundary (replaced with `(?<!\w)` - no word char before the current position is allowed - in the dynamic approach since `re.escape` might also support "words" like `.word.` and then `\b` might stop the regex from matching)
- `(example)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern):
  the `example` word
- `(?:\s+\1)+` - 1 or more occurrences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\1` - a backreference to the Group 1 value, that is, an `example` word
- `\b` - word boundary (replaced with `(?!\w)` - no word char after the current position is allowed).

Remember that in Python 2.x, you need to use `re.U` if you need to make `\b` word boundary Unicode-aware.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam I added code to handle situations when a word is a dynamic value and even in cases when the "word" might start/end with a non-word char.

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**: [`\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1)+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/j6c002/4) or `\b(example)(?:\s+\1)+\b` Substitution: `\1`

Details:

- `\b` Assert position at a word boundary
- `\w` Matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- `\s` Matches any whitespace character
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `\1` Group 1.

**Python code**:

```
text = 'my example example string contains example some text'

text = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1)+\b', r'\1', text)
```

Output:

```
my example string contains example some text
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/KZlek4)

Comment: As I understand it remove ANY word duplicates? I'm not sure at current moment, what I need any, but only specific maybe :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this in pure Python (without a `regex`), by creating a list of words and then generating a new `string` - applying your rules.

```
>>> words = my_str.split()
>>> ' '.join(w for i, w in enumerate(words) if w != words[i-1] or i == 0)
'my example string contains example some text'
```

Comment: Actually I need to implement it for every string in text, so one row answer is preferable :) anyway I like python-only solution! Thank you!

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam What do you mean by "for every string in text"?

Comment: I mean I have list of strings. So will wrap it with the loop (or using list comprehension). So I afraid using this method would be bulky

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam I see, well in that case, you could create a new list of the words and then do the `' '.join(...)` afterwards. Or, if the efficiency isn't too important, then you can simply replace the two occurrences of `words` *with* `my_str.split()`

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the .replace function:

```
my_str = 'my example example string contains example some text'
print my_str.replace("example example", "example")
```

Comment: the question is about the general case

Comment: They can be three or four or any in a row