# How to remove duplicate words (words are going not in a row) in file using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, file

I want to remove all the words which are duplicate from a file using regex.

For example:

```
 The university of Hawaii university began using began radio.
```

Output:

```
 The university of Hawaii began using radio.
```

I wrote this regex:

```
 String regex = "\\b(\\p{IsAlphabetic}+)(\\s+\\1\\b)+";
```

Which is removing only words which are going in a row after word.

For example: 
`The university university of Hawaii Hawaii began using radio.`

Output: `The university of Hawaii began using radio.`

My code with regex:

File dir = new File("C:/Users/Arnoldas/workspace/uplo/");

```
            String source = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "Output.txt";
            String dest = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "Final.txt";

            File fin = new File(source);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"));

            //FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(dest, true);
            OutputStreamWriter fstream = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(dest, true), "UTF-8");

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

            String regex = "\\b(\\p{IsAlphabetic}+)(\\s+\\1\\b)+";

            //String regex = "(?i)\\b([a-z]+)\\b(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            String aLine;
            while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

                Matcher m = p.matcher(aLine);
                while (m.find()) {
                    aLine = aLine.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1));
                }

                //Process each line and add output to *.txt file
                out.write(aLine);
                out.newLine();
                out.flush();
            }
```

Comment: You cannot do this with regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Streams instead:

```
String s = "The university university of Hawaii Hawaii began using radio.";
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

In this example the String is split along the blanks, than transformed to a stream. Duplicates are removed with distinct() and at the end all ist joined together with spaces between.

But this approach has a problem with the dot at the end. "radio" and "radio." are different words.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, but if between the repetitions there can be text
it must be done in a loop (for "began ... began ... began").

```
String s = "The university of Hawaii university began using began radio.";
for (;;) {
    String t = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(\\p{IsAlphabetic}+)\\b(.*?)\\s*\\b\\1\\b",
                            "$1$2");
    if (t.equals(s)) {
        break;
    }
    s = t;
}
```

For case-insensitive replace: use `(?i)`.

This is **very** inefficient as the regex must backtrack.

Simply throw all words in a `Set`.

```
// Java 9
Set<String> corpus = Set.of(s.split("\\P{IsAlphabetic}+"));

// Older java:
Set<String> corpus = new TreeSet<>();
Collections.addAll(set, s.split("\\P{IsAlphabetic}+"));

corpus.remove("");
```

---

***After comment***

- Correction of original code
- New style I/O using Files and Path, still no streams though
- Try-with-resources for automatic closing in and out
- Regex only to find a word with optional whitespace. Using a set to check duplicates.

  ```
      Path dir = Paths.get("C:/Users/Arnoldas/workspace/uplo");
      Path source = dir.resolve("Output.txt");
      String dest = dir.resolve("Final.txt");

      String regex = "(\\s*)\\b\\(p{IsAlphabetic}+)\\b";
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

      try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(source);
              BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(dest)) {
          String line;
          while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
              Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
              Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
              StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
              while (m.find()) {
                  boolean added = words.add(m.group(2).toLowerCase());
                  m.appendReplacement(sb, added ? m.group() : "");
              }
              m.appendTail(sb);
              out.write(sb.toString());
              out.newLine();
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: It seems nice, but could you take a look to my code? I am confused, how i could change it that set would work to me? @JoopEggen

Comment: but how to make it case insensitive?

Comment: The search already is case insensitive. The Set not, but I add toLowerCased words. (One could also make a case-insensitive set by adding a Comparator to the constructor.)

Comment: @ArnasArnelis sorry misunderstood last comment, case-insensitive with `String.replaceAll` works with `"(?i)"` - see answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
\b(\w+)\s+\1\b
Here \b is a word boundary and \1 references the captured match of the first group.
```

Source : [Regular Expression For Consecutive Duplicate Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: my regex string is regular expression but i needed \w+ to change that it could read lithuanian symbols

Comment: luthaninan symbols means?

Comment: Ąčęėįšųūž this is symbols of Lithuanian alphabet

Comment: Then I think you need to add checks for  all these symbols specifically