# Returning repeated words from a string

Tags: python

I have a string: "Are you ok? [Hello Hello Hello]. Yes I am! [Bye Bye Bye]"

I need to return ['Hello Hello Hello', 'Bye Bye Bye'] in a list.

Using a regular expression should be the easiest. I have tried findall() but it only returns the first word like Hello and Bye and not the entire string of [Hello Hello Hello] or [Bye Bye Bye]. I have also tried finditer() but that too is returning the only the first world.

```
text = "Are you ok? [Hello Hello Hello]. Yes I am! [Bye Bye Bye]"
def find_words(text):
    p = re.compile(r'(\w{3,})\s\1')
    for match in p.finditer(text):
        print(match.groups(0))
```

Expected result ['Hello Hello Hello', 'Bye Bye Bye']
When I run the code I get ['Hello', 'Bye']

Comment: Are the 3 words always surrounded by `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex?

`\b(\w+)\s+\1\b`

as from here [Regular Expression For Consecutive Duplicate Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words)