# How to find multiple space in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When one of columns contains target value, I write code following.

```
df['address'].str.contains('\t')
```

In my question, I would like to find multiple space which is more than 2 spaces.
I think I should use Regular expression.

How can I write code? Please give me an advice.

Comment: What you mean by multiple space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be a good example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 'b  ', 'c', '   d', '  e    ']})
         col
0        a
1      b
2        c
3        d
4    e
```

```
df['col'].str.contains('  *', regex=True)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
```

Answer (score 0):

One way use

```
s=pd.Series(['one ','more   than two','only  two'])
s.str.contains('  ')
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

If  we would like find the single space freq we could do `count`

```
s.str.count(' ')
0    1
1    4
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex based approach for any consecutive (potentially duplicate) words I posted is here: [Regular Expression For Consecutive Duplicate Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words/49459876#49459876)