# Regex to match sentences with adjacent and non-adjacent word repetition in R

Tags: r, regex, text, text-mining

I have a dataframe with sentences; in some sentences, words get used more than once:

```
df <- data.frame(Turn = c("well this is what the grumble about do n't they ?",
                          "it 's like being in a play-group , in n it ?",
                          "oh is that that steak i got the other night ?",
                          "well where have the middle sized soda stream bottle gone ?",
                          "this is a half day , right ? needs a full day",
                          "yourself , everybody 'd be changing your hair in n it ?",
                          "cos he finishes at four o'clock on that day anyway .",
                          "no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan .",
                          "yeah , i mean the the film was quite long though",
                          "it had steve martin in it , it 's a comedy",
                          "oh it is a dreary old day in n it ?",
                          "no it 's not mother theresa , it 's saint theresa .",
                          "oh have you seen that face lift job he wants ?",
                          "yeah bolshoi 's right so which one is it then ?"))
```

I want to match those sentences in which a word, any word, gets repeated once or more times.

**EDIT 1**:

The repeated words **can* be adjacent but they need not be. That's the reason why [Regular Expression For Consecutive Duplicate Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words) does not provide an answer to my question.

I've been modestly successful with this code:

```
df[grepl("(\\w+\\b\\s)\\1{1,}", df$Turn),]
[1] well this is what the grumble about do n't they ?      
[2] it 's like being in a play-group , in n it ?           
[3] oh is that that steak i got the other night ?          
[4] this is a half day , right ? needs a full day          
[5] yourself , everybody 'd be changing your hair in n it ?
[6] no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan .                  
[7] yeah , i mean the the film was quite long though       
[8] it had steve martin in it , it 's a comedy             
[9] oh it is a dreary old day in n it ?
```

The success is just modest because some sentences are matched that *should not* be matched, e.g., `yourself , everybody 'd be changing your hair in n it ?`, while others are not matched that *should be*, e.g., `no it 's not mother theresa , it 's saint theresa .`. How can the code be improved to produce exact matches?

**Expected result**:

```
df
                                                         Turn
2                it 's like being in a play-group , in n it ?
3               oh is that that steak i got the other night ?
5               this is a half day , right ? needs a full day
8                       no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan .
9            yeah , i mean the the film was quite long though
10                 it had steve martin in it , it 's a comedy
11                        oh it is a dreary old day in n it ?
12        no it 's not mother theresa , it 's saint theresa .
```

**EDIT 2**:

Another question would be how to define the *exact amount* of repeated words. The above, imperfect, regex matches words that are repeated at least once. If I change the quantifier to `{2}`, thus looking for a triple occurrence of a word, I'd get this code and this result:

```
df[grepl("(\\w+\\b\\s)\\1{2}", df$Turn),]
[1] no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan .         # "no" occurs 3 times
```

But again the match is imperfect as the **expected** result would be:

```
[1] no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan .          # "no" occurs 3 times
[2] it had steve martin in it , it 's a comedy     # "it" occurs 3 times
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `df[grepl("\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\b", df$Turn),]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `df[grepl("\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\b", df$Turn),]`matches only sentences in which the repeated words are adjacent! It does not match sentences where the repeated items are separated by other words.

Comment: Then `df[grepl("\\b(\\w+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b", df$Turn),]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `df[grepl("\\b(\\w+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b", df$Turn),]`matches **some** sentences with non-adjacent repetitions but fails to match others that should be matched!

Comment: If you do not explain the actual rules and do not provide an expected output, we can't help you more.

Comment: Ehm, `df[grepl("\\b(\\w+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b", df$Turn, perl=TRUE),]` works. You just need to tell R to use the PCRE regex engine. See [the R demo](https://rextester.com/OFVF51113). Actually, `df[grepl("\\b(\\w+)\\b.*?\\b\\1\\b", df$Turn, perl=TRUE),]` can also be used, and it does not make difference if you do not know if the repeated words appear close to one another or one is close to the start and the other is close to the end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, `df[grepl("\\b(\\w+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b", df$Turn, perl=TRUE),]`works, Thank you. What difference does the inclusion of `perl = T`make?

Comment: It has been already reported that using capturing groups and backreferences to them alongside with indefinitely quantified patterns  in TRE patterns yield unexpected results.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How would the code have to be changed if I want to match just sentences with a *certain number* of repetitions?

Comment: Are you changing the question now? It depends on what number: no more than, no fewer than or exacly N times.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Let's say I'd just want to match sentences where any word occurs exactly 3 times

Comment: Ok, so, shall we reopen and post the `df[grepl("\\b(\\w+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b", df$Turn, perl=TRUE),]` answer or do you want to edit the question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've edited the question; see **EDIT 1** and **EDIT 2** and would be grateful if you, or anybody else, could reopen the post

Comment: I think you need something like `exact_amount %in% table(strsplit(x, "\\W+"))`, see [this R demo](https://rextester.com/UIUDV66542) where `exact_amount <- 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option for defining the exact amount of repeated words.

**extract sentences in which the same words occur 3 times**

1. change regex.

   **(\s?\b\w+\b\s)(.*\1){2}**

   > (\s?\b\w+\b\s) captured by Group 1

   - \s? : blank space occurs zero or once.
   - \b\w+\b : the exact word character.
   - \s : blank space occurs once.

     > (.*\1) captured by Group 2

     - (.*\1) : **any characters that occur zero or more times before Group 1 matches again.**
     - (.*\1){2} :   Group 2 matches twice.

**Code**

```
df$Turn[grepl("(\\s?\\b\\w+\\b\\s)(.*\\1){2}", df$Turn, perl = T)]
# [1] "no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan ."     
# [2] "it had steve martin in it , it 's a comedy"
```

2. Use `strsplit(split="\\s")` split sentences into words.

   - use `sapply` and `table` to count the number of occurrence of words in each list element, and then select  sentences that satisfy the requirement.

**Code**

```
library(magrittr)
df$Turn %<>% as.character()
s<-strsplit(df$Turn,"\\s") %>% sapply(.,function(i)table(i) %>% .[.==3])
df$Turn[which(s!=0)]
# [1] "no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan ."     
# [2] "it had steve martin in it , it 's a comedy"
```

Hope this may help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would rather take another pass to handle this task. First, I added a group variable to the original data frame. Then, I counted how many times each word appears in each sentence and created a data frame, which is `mytemp`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mutate(df, id = 1:n()) -> df

mutate(df, id = 1:n()) %>% 
mutate(word = strsplit(x = Turn, split = " ")) %>% 
unnest(word) %>% 
count(id, word, name = "frequency", sort = TRUE) -> mytemp
```

Using this data frame, it is straightforward to identify sentences. I subset the data and obtained `id` for the sentences that have a word appearing three times. I similarly identified words that appeared more than once and obtained `id`. Finally, I subset the original data using the `id` numbers in `three` and `twice`.

```
# Search words that appear 3 times 

three <- filter(mytemp, frequency == 3) %>% 
         pull(id) %>% 
         unique()

# Serach words that appear more than once.

twice <- filter(mytemp, frequency > 1) %>% 
         pull(id) %>% 
         unique()

# Go back to the original data and handle subsetting
filter(df, id %in% three)

  Turn                                          id
  <chr>                                      <int>
1 no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan .          8
2 it had steve martin in it , it 's a comedy    10

filter(df, id %in% twice)

  Turn                                                   id
  <chr>                                               <int>
1 it 's like being in a play-group , in n it ?            2
2 oh is that that steak i got the other night ?           3
3 this is a half day , right ? needs a full day           5
4 no no no i 'm dave and you 're alan .                   8
5 yeah , i mean the the film was quite long though        9
6 it had steve martin in it , it 's a comedy             10
7 oh it is a dreary old day in n it ?                    11
8 no it 's not mother theresa , it 's saint theresa .    12
```