# Removing duplicate words without space in a vector in R

Tags: r, regex, duplicates

I can't figure out how to write a regular expression in R that would "match" only duplicate consecutive words without space such as:

```
Country<-c("GhanaGhana","Bangladesh","Pakistan","Mongolia","India",
"Indonesia","UgandaUganda","ArmeniaArmenia","Sri LankaSri Lanka",
"U.S. Virgin IslandsU.S. Virgin Islands")
```

and transform into this:

```
Country<-c("Ghana","Bangladesh","Pakistan","Mongolia","India","Indonesia",
           "Uganda","Armenia","Sri Lanka","U.S. Virgin Islands")
```

Traditional R function for this like `anyDuplicated()` or `unique()` is not working.  Is there a way to write a regular expression for this in R?

Comment: Another approach would be to write a function to check words with even nchar by splitting them in the middle and in case of duplicates only keep one of the two.

Comment: I agree with @user12728748 - this would not be easy to do with regular expressions.

Answer (score 6):

```
stringr::str_replace(Country, "^(.*)\\1$", "\\1")
# [1] "Ghana"               "Bangladesh"          "Pakistan"            "Mongolia"            "India"              
# [6] "Indonesia"           "Uganda"              "Armenia"             "Sri Lanka"           "U.S. Virgin Islands"

## or in base (using perl = TRUE for efficiency)
sub("^(.*)\\1$", "\\1", Country, perl = TRUE)
## same result
```

In general, the pattern `"^(.*)\\1$"` matches a string that is entirely a repeated sequence - `(.*)` creates a matching group, and `\\1` refers to the first matching group (just learned that using `\\1` in the pattern itself is possible, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2823037/903061)). We replace the entire repeated string with the first matching group.

Comment: If the strings are long, do not rely on the default TRE library. Use PCRE then, `sub("^(.*)\\1$", "\\1", Country, perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 4):

You can compare the first half of the string against the second half, if the are the same then cut it in half

```
DoubledStrings <- substring(Country, 1, nchar(Country)/2 ) == substring(Country, nchar(Country)/2+1, nchar(Country))
Country[DoubledStrings] <- substring(Country, 1, nchar(Country)/2 )[DoubledStrings]

> Country
 [1] "Ghana"               "Bangladesh"          "Pakistan"           
 [4] "Mongolia"            "India"               "Indonesia"          
 [7] "Uganda"              "Armenia"             "Sri Lanka"          
[10] "U.S. Virgin Islands"
```

Comment: If the strings are at all long, I wouldn't be surprised if this answer quickly becomes much more efficient than regex.