# Pandas: Merge two string columns in Python, remove duplicated strings and remove unwanted string unless only unwanted string left

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge two string columns and I wish to get rid of `'others'` if the counter value is a 'non-others' value - like `'apple' + 'others' = 'apple'` but `'others' + 'others' = 'others'`. I managed the 2nd condition but how can I accommodate the two conditions on the merge?

```
data = {'fruit1':["organge", "apple", "organge", "organge", "others"],
        'fruit2':["apple", "others", "organge", "watermelon", "others"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["together"] = df["fruit1"] + ' ' + df["fruit2"]
df["together"] = df["together"].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(pd.unique(x.split())))

    fruit1      fruit2            together
0  organge       apple       organge apple
1    apple      others        apple others
2  organge     organge             organge
3  organge  watermelon  organge watermelon
4   others      others              others
```

Expected output:

```
    fruit1      fruit2            together
0  organge       apple       organge apple
1    apple      others               apple
2  organge     organge             organge
3  organge  watermelon  organge watermelon
4   others      others              others
```

Comment: What is the counter value?

Comment: If you look at row index 1, that would be 'apple' in this case. So when joining the two columns, if there's another value other than 'others', I wish to remove the 'others' but keep the value like 'apple'.

Comment: What happens if you have an others in the first column? Like others, apple

Comment: In this case, you can look at row index 4 where 'others' + 'others' = 'others'.

Comment: But what about 'others' + 'apple'? Is the result 'apple' or 'others apple'?

Comment: Good question! That would be the result 'apple'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace `others` by `NaN` and `dropna()` during `join` followed by replacing empty string by a single `others`:

```
df["together"] = (df[['fruit1', 'fruit2']].replace('others', np.nan)
                   .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(pd.unique(x.dropna())), axis=1)
                   .replace('', 'others')
                 )
```

Or leveraging the `str.replace` with `n=1` by @Dani (caution: won't work if ther are 3 columns to aggregate; may leave 2 instances of `others`) and combining the remove duplicate logics of OP, as follows:

```
df["together"] = (df["fruit1"] + " " + df["fruit2"]).str.replace("others", "", n=1).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(pd.unique(x.split())))
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

    fruit1      fruit2            together
0  organge       apple       organge apple
1    apple      others               apple
2  organge     organge             organge
3  organge  watermelon  organge watermelon
4   others      others              others
```

Comment: Just run through the thing again and you're right. Just checked yours and it works as expected. I was so focused on removing the others but ignored on the duplicate condition. Thanks for pointing out the porblem!

Comment: @codedancer  You are welcome!  And take note that if you have 3 columns to aggregate, it may also just remove one and leave with 2 `others`.  Anyway, it's a very good feature to learn.

Comment: I am wondering if there's a way we can prevent this when more columns are involved.

Comment: @codedancer  My first solution replacing `others` by `NaN` works for more columns.

Comment: Just tested it on a large scale, it works as you suggested!

Comment: @codedancer  That's great it works for you in a large scale too!  Happy programming  :-)

Answer (score 5):

You want to replace only one `"others"`, so simple join and then use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) once:

```
df["together"] = (df["fruit1"] + " " + df["fruit2"]).str.replace("others", "", n=1).str.strip()
print(df)

    fruit1      fruit2            together
0  organge       apple       organge apple
1    apple      others               apple
2  organge     organge     organge organge
3  organge  watermelon  organge watermelon
4   others      others              others
```

The `n` parameter specifies the number of replacements to be made, from the documentation:

> **n** int, default -1 (all)
> Number of replacements to make from start.

**UPDATE**

To also remove duplicates use the following regular expression:

```
df["together"] = df["together"].str.replace(r"\b(\w+)\s+\1\b", r"\1", n=1, regex=True).str.strip()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    fruit1      fruit2            together
0  organge       apple       organge apple
1    apple      others               apple
2  organge     organge             organge
3  organge  watermelon  organge watermelon
4   others      others              others
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-duplicate-words) an explanation of the regex.

Comment: Elegantly done! Thanks!

Comment: @codedancer This does not remove duplicates.  Note the `organge organge` in result.

Comment: @codedancer Could you clarify on this?

Comment: I think @SeaBean's comment is correct. It doesn't remove the duplicate value. I tried to make it 3 steps again - doing mine first and yours later but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
def merge_columns(df, col1, col2, new_col, unwanted_string):
    '''Merge two string columns and replace unwanted string with existing string'''
    df[new_col] = df[col1].astype(str) + df[col2].astype(str)
    df[new_col] = df[new_col].str.replace(unwanted_string, '')
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a lambda function as follows (copy-pasting it will work):

```
df.together = df.together.apply(lambda x: x if 'others' not in x else ('others' if all([y == '' for y in x.split('others')]) else x.replace('others', '').strip()))
```

Giving you:

```
    fruit1  fruit2      together
0   organge apple       organge apple
1   apple   others      apple
2   organge organge     organge
3   organge watermelon  organge watermelon
4   others  others      others
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the resulting value based on an if-statement and the `fruit_x` value. To do so, I suggest to [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) `others` with `None` which makes conditional checking and re-replacing very easy. Call [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` to a perform row-wise operation which I implemented in a separate function `concat_strings` for sake of readability. In addition, I would chain all required operations in a single statement in order to not change the original data set.

A very basic approach could look like this:

```
import pandas as pd


def concat_strings(row):
    fruit_1 = row['fruit1']
    fruit_2 = row['fruit2']

    if fruit_1 == fruit_2:
        return fruit_1
    elif fruit_1 and fruit_2:
        return fruit_1 + ' ' + fruit_2
    elif fruit_1:
        return fruit_1
    elif fruit_2:
        return fruit_2


# create dataframe
data = {
    'fruit1': ["organge", "apple", "organge", "organge", "others"],
    'fruit2': ["apple", "others", "organge", "watermelon", "others"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# replace "others" with None to use as boolean later
# concat strings
# replace None values with "others" to get desired output
df["together"] = (
    df
    .replace({"others": None})
    .apply(concat_strings, axis=1)
    .replace({None: "others"})
)

# print final results
print(df)
```

Resulting output:

```
      fruit1      fruit2            together
  0  organge       apple       organge apple
  1    apple      others               apple
  2  organge     organge             organge
  3  organge  watermelon  organge watermelon
  4   others      others              others
```