# javascript. remove adjacent duplicate commas from string

Tags: javascript

```
var ad_pop="Floor 19, , 43 Varick Street, New York, NY"
```

Tried this. but didn't work.

```
alert(ad_pop.replace(/[, ]+/g, " ").trim());
```

expected output:

```
Floor 19, 43 Varick Street, New York, NY
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-duplicate-words looks helpful. --- Try using the regex `/(, +)\1/g` replacing with `$1`?

Comment: `replace(/,\W+,/g, ",")` - replace all commas that are followed by an arbitrary amount of whitespace and then another comma, with one single comma.

Comment: Why is this tagged with jQuery?