# How to check if a message was repeated in multiple lines in REGEX PCRE2 flavor twitch chatterinoi?

Tags: regex, twitch, twitch-api, pcre2

I am trying to make Chatterino (Twitch chat) warn me when the same message is sent over and over again.
Chatterino uses **REGEX PCRE2** flavor to check if pattern was sent in chat.
^*bot*\b == warning when someone typed the word "bot" once.
I wanted to create a warning for repeated messages from different users.
example:

user0: nice     -->*no warning*
user1: nice     -->*warning*

The warning should occur not only for the word *nice*, but for every word that is repeated in sequence
Is it possible?

The [wiki](https://wiki.chatterino.com/Regex/) shows me these lines:
x*  x, repeated any number of times
x+  x, repeated any number of times but at least 1

But from what I've noticed, it warns me when a *x* is repeated within the same message.
I want the warning to occur when different messages are *x*

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-duplicate-words. In PCRE you can [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) a word and if you want to check for multiple duplicate words, you can use a lookahead to check if the captured word occurs again. Something like [`\b(\w+)\b(?=.+\b\1\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/I9sZWv/1)

Comment: I tried that solution, but I couldn't change it so it would compare the words in other messages and not in the same line. 
Example: msg1="I like music" msg2="I like bananas" nothing is captured and that's what I'm after. 
The only case that code captures is "I like like music" not what I'm looking for.

Comment: To make it match across lines you need to prepend the `(?s)` flag like in the linked demo. If this is not available, you can use `[\s\S]+` instead of `.+` like [in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/I9sZWv/3).