# How to keep the duplicated matched patterns from re.search() multiple strings?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, duplicates

This question below is different from [Regular Expression for duplicate words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-duplicate-words). The linked question solves finding and returning duplicate matched patterns from a single string, such as "the the ..." or "my question, my answer" which return ['the', 'the'] or ['my', 'my']. My problem is when I use "*re.search()*" in a for loop and hoping it can return multiple duplicates from multiple strings. My regex search pattern is a number followed by 4 different characters from a-z in small cap. Ex. 2inch. See the code below for what I have tried so far:

```
import re
names = ['1_abc-2inch-scatter', '1_abc-2inch-uniform', '2_abc-3inch-scatter', '2_abc-3inch-uniform']
sizes = []
for name in names:
    sizes = re.search('\d[A-Za-z]+', name).group()
    print(sizes)
```

Output:

```
['3inch']
```

Expected output:

```
['2inch', '2inch', '3inch', '3inch']
```

I'm not sure why the code seems to overwrite duplicated search results and only returned the last one matched. I want the expected output to be returned. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

you are overwriting the `sizes` variable in each iteration of the loop, try this:

```
import re

names = ['1abc-2inch-scatter', '1abc-2inch-uniform', '2abc-3inch-scatter', '2abc-3inch-uniform']
sizes = []

for name in names:
    match = re.search(r'\d[A-Za-z]+', name)
    if match:
        sizes.append(match.group())

print(sizes)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could make use of [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) without looping:

```
print(re.findall(r'\d[A-Za-z]+', ' '.join(names)))
```

Or you can concatenate the resulting list from re.findall with `sizes[]` for every iteration:

```
for name in names:
    sizes += re.findall(r'\d[A-Za-z]+', name)
```

Output

```
['2inch', '2inch', '3inch', '3inch']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Python/Re expert, but is this what you want?

```py
import re


def get_size(name):
    size = []
    for i in name:
        size.append(re.findall(r'\d+inch', i)[0])
    return size


print(get_size(names))
```

Prints:

```
['2inch', '2inch', '3inch', '3inch']
```

Answer (score 1):

For your needs, you can join the data and use `re.finditer` to concoct your `sizes` list. This method will only compile the regex one time, and turns the "working" part of your code into one simple line.

```
import re

names    = ['1_abc-2inch-scatter', '1_abc-2inch-uniform', '2_abc-3inch-scatter', '2_abc-3inch-uniform']

finditer = re.compile(r'\d[a-z]+', re.I).finditer

sizes    = [m.group() for m in finditer(' '.join(names))]

print(sizes) #['2inch', '2inch', '3inch', '3inch']
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... My problem is when I use "re.search()" in a for loop and hoping it can return multiple duplicates from multiple strings. ..."*

The *[re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)* method is going to return only the first match.

There is the *[re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)* method, which will return all occurrences as a *list* or *tuple*.
And, there is the *[re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer)* method, which will return all occurrences as an iterator.

Furthermore, in your code, you should be using *[list.append](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures)*.

```py
import re
names = ['1_abc-2inch-scatter', '1_abc-2inch-uniform', '2_abc-3inch-scatter', '2_abc-3inch-uniform']
sizes = []
for name in names:
    for string in re.findall(r'\d[A-Za-z]+', name):
        sizes.append(string)
print(sizes)
```

Output

```
['2inch', '2inch', '3inch', '3inch']
```